# Jquery loop through table trs and append div tag to current tr

Tags: jquery, html, append

I have the following html code.

```
    <table class="table">
<thead>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="size"/>
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter quantity here.."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="size"/>
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter quantity here.."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="size"/>
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter quantity here.."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="size"/>
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter quantity here.."/>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

And I am doing loop through each tr in tbody and getting each input values. But I wanna append `<div class="error-message">Error Message Here..</div>`. So I want following output as below.

```
<table class="table">
<thead>
    <th>Size</th>
    <th>Quantity</th>
</thead>

<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="size"/>
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter quantity here.."/>
            <div class="error-message">Error Message Here..</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="size"/>
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter quantity here.."/>
            <div class="error-message">Error Message Here..</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="size"/>
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter quantity here.."/>
            <div class="error-message">Error Message Here..</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="name">
            <input type="hidden" value="2" name="size"/>
        </td>
        <td class="description">
            <input type="text" name="quantity" class="input-xlarge" placeholder="Enter quantity here.."/>
            <div class="error-message">Error Message Here..</div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

The javascript as below.

```
$('.table > tbody tr').each(function() {
        var size_id = $(this).children('.name').find('input').val();
        var quantity = $(this).children('.description').find('input').val();
        $(this).find('.description').append('<div class="error-message">Error Message Here..</div>');
}
```

But I am not getting that output. Please suggest me hoe to do that.

Comment: Are you getting correct excepted values in your variables size_id and quantity ?

Comment: @EnterJQ. Yes. But that div tag not appending

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You missed **);** at the end. See this [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/zyXQC/2/)

```
$('.table > tbody tr').each(function () {
    var size_id = $(this).children('.name').find('input').val();
    var description = $(this).children('.description');
    var quantity = description.find('input').val();
    description.append('<div class="error-message">Error Message Here..</div>');
});
```

Comment: Who downvoted this and why? I too see the same problem there. Put one ")" at the end and it is working fine.

Comment: not me but just on a seperate note I would have cached the `$(this).children('.description')` variable: http://jsfiddle.net/zyXQC/2/